# Angular variable in component not rendering in template

Tags: node.js, angular, templates, components

**Answer: I was using title: 'myTitle' instead of title = 'myTitle' ;(**

I have just generated a new Angular app with one new component. 
The problem is when i initialize a variable inside the class component and  try to output it in the template using {{}} it is not showing variable's value.

In the main - App-Root Component it is written just like my code but there it is working :(

**content.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.sass']
})

export class ContentComponent {
  title: 'Content'
}
```

**content.component.html**

```
<h3>{{title}}</h3>
```

Comment: show us the code

Comment: We need to see some code :)

Comment: sorry, i have added code <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should bind values :

In `component.ts` :

```
public title:any = 'Content';
```

in `component.html`  :

```
<h1> {{title}} </h1>
```

Here is a working example : [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfmjmc)

Answer (score 0):

Use the angular variable as below
title: string="Content"
For eg
Try this, I have created a sample MyComponent class as below.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  private myVariable:string="Hello World"
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

my-component.component.html

```
<p>
{{myVariable}}
</p>
```

Make sure add the above component in app.component.html which is the bootstrapping component as below

```
<app-my-component></app-my-component>
```

also in app.module as below in declartion section

```
 declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TopBarComponent,
    ProductListComponent,
    MyComponentComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
```